# Find armature pose from shape key?

Tags: shape-keys

I'm curious if there's a way to find the corresponding armature pose from a shape key?

Comment: I don't think so. Many shapes wouldn't even be reproducible with just armatures, right?

Comment: @Leander, or if the shape key has been created from a pose itself? But would be a really big equation system to solve...

Comment: @Leander Agree, but what about finding the closest shape from armature pose?

Comment: @June Do you have basic knowledge of python and would be willing to use a script?

Comment: @Leander A little, wouldn't mind using a script at all.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have you mesh in a shape with *Shapekey1* at `1.0` and want to reproduce that shape with *Shapekey1* at `0.0`, but with an armature deformation instead.

Comment: @Leander Correct.

Comment: imho, this is not resolvable if you don't have more specific constraints. Like amount of bones, geometry of the mesh. Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: @lemon think amount of bones shouldn’t matter, we can find the according deforming bones of the deformed verts by weights, try out local combinations of the bones to match the shape with some searching algorithm. Neither does geometry of the mesh matter, other than reducing workload if mirrored. No I don’t have a concret example,  but working on it in the meantime.

Comment: So you mean, bones and weights are known? Maybe something like 'simulated annealing' can do the job (not sure, of course).